# RelatedToId field on EmailMessage Not Writeable

Tags: apex, emailmessage

I am getting this response 'Field is not writeable: EmailMessage.RelatedToId'

Email trigger helper method is the following:

```
public static void parseEmailSubjectForLeadRelation(List<EmailMessage> emailList){
        system.debug('Entered parseEmailSubjectForLeadRelation');
        List<EmailMessage> emList = new List<EmailMessage>();
        string leadId;
        for(EmailMessage email : emailList) {
            system.debug('email == ' + email.TextBody + ' / ' + email.ParentId);
            if(email.Incoming == true && email.ParentId != null && email.TextBody != null) {
                if(email.TextBody.contains('reference:')){
                    email.RelatedToId = email.TextBody.substringBetween('reference:{', '}');
                    emList.add(email);
                }
            }
        }
        update emList;
}
```

This is being called on AfterInsert. I have seen another similar question that was fixed by updating the api version of the apex class which i have already tried. I have also double checked that enhanced email is enabled in this org.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm) for the EmailMessage Object, this field can only be set on `insert` not `update`

Comment: Wow ! thank you Bryan, i knew there was some rule i was just not realizing. I believe i can take it from here. Thanks!

Comment: In Summer'23 a new [permission](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_service_email_user_perm.htm&release=244&type=5) was added. Users with this permission can update this field.